# Unable to find Virtualization option in bios settings

Tags: virtualization, bios, hypervisor

I am trying to install docker desktop, for this virtualization need to be enabled.But I am not able to find this option in bios settings on HP Pavilion laptop. I am using windows 10 operating system.

Any suggestion???

I tried to update bios version but not able to update.